# Android web-client (phone, table) bad works with IIS 7

Tags: android, asp.net, iis

I have a IIS7 web-site on Windows 2008.
From java-script I write mp3-file by http-handler:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
audio.src = GetMultimedia.ashx?F=" + filename;
audio.load();
audio.play();
```

GetMultimedia.ashx:

```
 Response.ClearHeaders();
 Response.ClearContent();
 Response.Clear();
 Response.ContentType = "audio/mp3";
 Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileLength().ToString());
 Response.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
 Response.BufferOutput = true;

   GetFile(ref FileBuffer);  // I get buffer of mp3-file for writing to Response
   if (FileBuffer != null)
   {
     ms = new MemoryStream(FileBuffer, 0, FileBuffer.Length, true);
     if (Response.IsClientConnected == true)
     {
       ms.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
       Response.Flush();
      }
   }
```

Problem: on Windows any browsers work fine, but on Android (Opera, internal browser) http-handler works 12 times (log below). IIS write retcode 200 0 64, after this handler calling 11 times. So, mp3-file in Response different from original because http-handler calling multiple time.

```
2012-11-11 15:54:13 GET /GetMultimedia.ashx V=f.mp3 HTTP/1.1 stagefright/1.2+(Linux;Android+4.0.3) 200 0 64 1069317 261 8626
2012-11-11 15:54:13 GET /GetMultimedia.ashx V=f.mp3 HTTP/1.1 stagefright/1.2+(Linux;Android+4.0.3) 200 0 0 2236677 261 8330
2012-11-11 15:56:15 GET /GetMultimedia.ashx V=f.mp3 HTTP/1.1 stagefright/1.2+(Linux;Android+4.0.3) 200 0 0 255 284 140
2012-11-11 15:56:18 GET /GetMultimedia.ashx V=f.mp3 HTTP/1.1 stagefright/1.2+(Linux;Android+4.0.3) 200 0 0 255 284 140
2012-11-11 15:56:22 GET /GetMultimedia.ashx V=f.mp3 HTTP/1.1 stagefright/1.2+(Linux;Android+4.0.3) 200 0 0 255 284 296
2012-11-11 15:56:25 GET /GetMultimedia.ashx V=f.mp3 HTTP/1.1 stagefright/1.2+(Linux;Android+4.0.3) 200 0 0 255 284 124
2012-11-11 15:56:29 GET /GetMultimedia.ashx V=f.mp3 HTTP/1.1 stagefright/1.2+(Linux;Android+4.0.3) 200 0 0 255 284 249
2012-11-11 15:56:32 GET /GetMultimedia.ashx V=f.mp3 HTTP/1.1 stagefright/1.2+(Linux;Android+4.0.3) 200 0 0 255 284 171
2012-11-11 15:56:35 GET /GetMultimedia.ashx V=f.mp3 HTTP/1.1 stagefright/1.2+(Linux;Android+4.0.3) 200 0 0 255 284 140
2012-11-11 15:56:38 GET /GetMultimedia.ashx V=f.mp3 HTTP/1.1 stagefright/1.2+(Linux;Android+4.0.3) 200 0 0 255 284 140
2012-11-11 15:56:41 GET /GetMultimedia.ashx V=f.mp3 HTTP/1.1 stagefright/1.2+(Linux;Android+4.0.3) 200 0 0 255 284 140
2012-11-11 15:56:44 GET /GetMultimedia.ashx V=f.mp3 HTTP/1.1 stagefright/1.2+(Linux;Android+4.0.3) 200 0 0 255 284 109
```